# Why isn't this class specialization using a concept accepted?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code attempts to partially specialize a class using a concept and add a method to the specialization, but it is rejected by clang 11.0.0:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> // note: previous template declaration is here
struct S {};

template <std::integral T>
struct S<T>
{
    void f();
};

template <std::integral T> // error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
void S<T>::f()
{
}
```

clang gives the error message:

```
<source>:14:16: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
template <std::integral T>
               ^
<source>:3:11: note: previous template declaration is here
template <typename T>
```

(see https://godbolt.org/z/Wv1ojK). Why is this code wrong? Or is this a bug in clang? (FWIW, this code is accepted by gcc trunk and by MSVC 19.28, although that's no guarantee of correctness.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely a CLANG bug. It is already filed - [#48020](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48020).

Comment: I ran into this also. Is there a work-around for this? This is the first thing I tried to do using concepts and it doesn't work.