# Member definition of partially specialized classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, partial-specialization

I'm trying to define member functions of partially specialized class templates, but different compilers have wildly different opinions of what I'm allowed to do and why.

Let's take this slowly and start with something that works for all main compilers (all = gcc, clang and msvc):

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
concept Integer
= std::is_same_v<T,int> || std::is_same_v<T,unsigned int>;

template <class T>
concept FloatingPoint
= std::is_same_v<T,float> || std::is_same_v<T,double>;


template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    T get() {return 0;}
};

template <Integer T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    T get(){ return 0; }
};

template <FloatingPoint T>
struct Foo<T>
{
    T get(){ return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<char>().get();
    Foo<int>().get();
    Foo<float>().get();
}
```

Examples on godbolt: [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/8xP3q7), [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/nP4oPG), [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/j9K54W)

Cool, but I want to separate declarations and definitons of the member functions. Let's move the definiton *one of the specialized classes*.
Examples: [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/5qqbK7), [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/qTzjWs), [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/69G71j). GCC and MSVC both work fine, but Clang fails to correctly match the member definition to the correct declaration.

No worries, I was never planning to use Clang anyway. Let's try separating the other specialized definition from its declaration too. Example: [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/cz6z6d), [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/8fqGd8), [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/dTb7nb). GCC continues to deliver, Clang gives more of the same errors, and MSVC complains that I've redefined a member...

Who is right? Do I have a fundamental misconception about partial template specialization? How do I get this working on MSVC?

### Edit 2023 September

Clang 17.0.1 fixed the issue and manages to compile the example. The latest MSVC still fails.

Comment: I haven't yet looked at the linked examples, but there's an unwritten Stackoverflow rule: any question that shows a compiler variance is worth an automatic upvote.

Comment: At least for clang, the ```type constraint differs in template redeclaration```-error you are facing appears to be a bug. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782324/8359552).

Comment: @samv I dunno, if it is just msvc disagreeing, that would seem too easy.  ;)

Comment: imho including working code and godbolt links make a nice add-on, but the essential information: The broken code and the error message are not included in this question

Comment: Notice that godbolt provides conformance view to see all compiler at once [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T4MoWo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Who is right?

GCC is correct to accept all the cases, whereas Clang and MSVC are wrong to reject them; out-of class-definitions of partial specializations shall be matched to their declarations by equivalent *template-head*:s, which includes constraints, if any.

The *template-head* of the primary template of `Foo` is not equivalent to the *template-head* of the two constrained partial specializations of it, and the definition of the primary template shall therefor not conflict with out-of-class definitions to member functions of constrained specializations of it.

> Do I have a fundamental misconception about partial template specialization?

No, not from the looks of this question.

> How do I get this working on MSVC?

As MSVC, like Clang, seems to (currently) have problems differentiating *template-head*:s for out-of-class definitions (particularly shown when partially specializing a class template by means of constraints), you will need to avoid the latter whilst compiling with MSVC (for now). As there may not be an associated MSVC bug report, you may want to consider filing one.

---

#### Details

As per [[temp.spec.partial.general]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.general#4) a partial specialization may indeed be constrained:

> A partial specialization may be constrained ([temp.constr]). [Example
> 2:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C = true;
>
> template<typename T> struct X { };
> template<typename T> struct X<T*> { };          // #1
> template<C T> struct X<T> { };                  // #2
> ```
>
> [...] — end example]

as long as [the declaration of the primary template precedes it](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.general#1.sentence-2).

We may minimize your example into the following:

```
template <typename>
concept C = true;

template <typename T>
struct S;

template <C T>
struct S<T> { void f(); };

template <C T> 
void S<T>::f() {}
```

which GCC accepts but Clang rejects

> prog.cc:12:12: error: out-of-line definition of `f` from class `S<T>` without definition
>
> ```
> void S<T>::f() {}
>      ~~~~~~^
> ```

meaning Clang interprets the out-of-class definition

```
template <C T> 
void S<T>::f() {}
```

as having a [*template-head*](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:template-head) that is equivalent to that of the primary template, which is wrong, as the *template-head* includes [*template-parameter*:s](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#nt:template-parameter) which in turn includes [*type-parameter*:s](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#nt:type-parameter) which in turn includes [*type-constraints*:s](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#nt:type-constraint), if any.

The *equivalence* of *template-head*:s is governed by [[temp.over.link]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6), which includes constraints [**emphasis** mine]:

> *Two *template-heads* are *equivalent* if* their *template-parameter-lists* have the same length, corresponding *template-parameters* are equivalent and **are both declared with *type-constraints* that are equivalent if either template-parameter is declared with a *type-constraint***, and if either *template-head* has
> a *requires-clause*, they both have *requires-clauses* and the
> corresponding *constraint-expressions* are equivalent.

Finally, albeit non-normative, both *Example 2* of [[temp.mem]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem) and

> [...] A member template can be defined within or outside its class
> definition or class template definition. A member template of a class
> template that is defined outside of its class template definition
> **shall be specified with a *template-head* equivalent to that of the class template** followed by a *template-head* equivalent to that of
> the member template ([temp.over.link]). [...]
>
> [ Example 2:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C1 = true;
> template<typename T> concept C2 = sizeof(T) <= 4;
>
> template<C1 T> struct S {
>   template<C2 U> void f(U);
>   template<C2 U> void g(U);
> };
>
> template<C1 T> template<C2 U>
> void S<T>::f(U) { }             // OK
> template<C1 T> template<typename U>
> void S<T>::g(U) { }             // error: no matching function in S<T>
> ```
>
> — end example]

and *Example 2* of [[temp.class.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.general#example-2):

> [ Example 2:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> template<typename T> concept C = true;
> template<typename T> concept D = true;
>
> template<C T> struct S {
>   void f();
>   void g();
>   void h();
>   template<D U> struct Inner;
> };
>
> template<C A> void S<A>::f() { }        // OK: template-heads match
> template<typename T> void S<T>::g() { } // error: no matching declaration for S<T>
>
> template<typename T> requires C<T>      // ill-formed, no diagnostic required: template-heads are
> void S<T>::h() { }                      // functionally equivalent but not equivalent
>
> template<C X> template<D Y>
> struct S<X>::Inner { };                 // OK
> ```
>
> — end example]

show example of out-of-class definitions of member functions of constrained class template specializations.

This is, particularly, Clang bug:

- [Bug 48020 - Defining constrained member function out of line is rejected](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48020)

I'm not aware whether there is a similar bug report for MSVC or not.

Comment: Awesome and informative answer, thank you! I filed an [issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Out-of-line-definition-of-a-constrained-/1306502) as you suggested (though Microsoft's wonderful website stripped the template arguments from the code...)