# Forward Declaration of Constrained Template Specializations

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, partial-specialization

I've been doing constrained partial class template specializations using C++20 concepts for a while now and they work great, but I and ran into a problem when attempting to forward declare them: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM1ykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn4Btpj2RQwNTQQlkTFxibaNza25HQrjA2FD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5glhyN5YANQmCW5oDFvJBAqn2CYaAIIPjwSYLMkGbydnB0wKCiOABU7i8LlcCEcAJKCTDAOI/AAiRxm6BAIDwCgA%2BgpWJgsQA3U5uIHkQR3E4AdjcJmpKIIaIx2NxbEJxNJXgY6WA4XQRzCBFBCSsTxebw%2BX0wP3OBgBwNBT3BmGuRwAYrRUExIadkaj0ZicXi2WdSVQNVqKbSaXS9UzDayiSbSOh1tF6EKRc8nuLPlqpcS/nKQQl7orZYChC9aVZKYjTp6xe9fd9iTC3vDiPKQ2Dw0dIyaPVGngB6YvAhCYo78YgAdyafKwf2IWsyR2ixEwTAA1oCAOJuGnepOS6XqzWQ4Ohx6BiPswuiocSv3StNwhGTnP/WcF7OiykxuPCouvYfL4ljrVZqczvNz3fPfe0w8Jp4Co4sJhhCDLKOPp5HADbzOAUKWxECj3/QD8zcM1x1ArFYItCCH0RDhVloTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBOBpSxrBRdZNn9MwEh4UgCE0NDVi7EBMI0fROEkHD6IIzheAUEBWLovC0NIOBYBgRAQEwVRai8IgyAoCAmmABRlEMLohAQVAa1wmi0A%2BOgWwEVTwloDStNw/C9OSOgRmALgOismziAAeVksztK4qTakeYhlJ4oJpOQBp8Fw3h%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUITSF0Mx9EMYxrGsfQ8GiPjIFWVBrkyPiOAAWlRHVTBIywzHwhRyK2PRUTCYz1M0jzuF4AgO22Gia2bZJOB4dCsM4pLCI4bBAtkkgjlUAAOAA2UrFskI5gGQZAjnsgA6LgjggYirEsUgjlwQhZt2Lhli6%2BjllWBBOyweJvzYjgONIFgQASDQdo0Sl5vszDSAs3gJt4/jaLukTxIgJAvOQGb5MoJSVLU0z2p03hHK%2BTJWox8yuJxkY/iMKQNFY4mXLczHPMCny/I4XgEeCsJ/PC4RRHEGKOfitQuN0JIDCMFBMpO2gcry17Cp6EryoZSqxYsWreIa6KxhC/H3Kx2ieqG3h%2BqYQbOpGjhsJBriJqmmS5LmpaVrW0ngG2yQ/r%2Bg6jqys78Ftq6bqhoT7tIR6mGeyhTY%2Br6fr%2BgGgYt8b/L4gTodEiSEaR8gUd8tGTO1/XSBxwyGC12mkqpkACWQZJkkJLgAE4sWorFVFWgvUH0%2BhqeEUv8IRhmSuZwLWdC2LOaiiRpF5pR%2BaS3RAmFjLqpsCXcvgAqioEEriz1KrjuVuq1aahkWvRvPOt1zBeoNgb9dN83Qe4ybpttlu1pYBRK6OAl6526iPaV0651fZUWurdQOD0nojFehhd6vAo51x2vNSQCRKTAwfuDWwkNBJaCDkxFib0EhjXwhg7BDE3pmCIWDfypCg4EjiOkZwkggA%3D%3D)

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept Integer = std::is_same_v<T,int> || std::is_same_v<T,unsigned int>;

template <class T>
concept Float = std::is_same_v<T,float> || std::is_same_v<T,double>;

template <class T>
class S
{};

template <Integer T>
class S<T>;

// This forward declaration breaks GCC
template <Float T>
class S<T>;

template <Integer T>
class S<T>
{};

template <Float T>
class S<T>
{};

int main()
{
    S<int> s_int;
    S<float> s_float;
}
```

The second forward declaration

```
// This forward declaration breaks GCC
template <Float T>
class S<T>;
```

breaks GCC, but Clang and MSVC have no issues with it. I've had [very similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667790/member-definition-of-partially-specialized-classes) with concepts in the past (which still haven't been fixed yet) but it was the other way around: GCC was conformant yet Clang and MSVC incorrectly rejected the code.

Ditching concepts and explicitly specializing for `int` and `float` is accepted by GCC as well ([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm25oDGsJBApH2CYaAIK3dwSYLAkGz4fHu0wKCvsAKtdHqdzgR9gBJQSYYDRT4AEX2E3QIBAeAUAH0FKxMOiAG5HNz/ciCa6HADsbhMFMRBGRqIxWLYeIJRK8DBSwBC6H2wQIQM2Vnuj2er3emE%2BJwMvwBQPuIMwF32ADFaKgmGCjgikSi0ZjsczjkSqKr1aSqZTqdr6XqmfjDaR0MsIvR%2BYKHvcRW91eKCd9pYDNjc5VK/kJHlSrGS4Uc3cKXl6PgTZXc/aGCbzXeGPfGxRLk6n9mHjsa1XzAzGs08c968%2BXgz808cM3WHmTI9GBZXPbmky2C0W3CXTS2I1SO7H7rz9iwmMEIPNw23HvsV4X0yTA4j0c23au18WTWXsFuh2XY1GOItaJxYrw/BwtKRUJxKZZrIjlqsfWZNjxSARNEvRYAGsQFiDR9E4SQ70Ap9OF4BQQAggCH0vUg4FgGBEBATBVEqLwiDICgIDqYAFGUQw2iEBBUAAd3vP80FeOh1TSCiQloai6PvR8mISOgBmALgzBaPiBOIAB5AiuPo2DcMqO5iDI%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%2BBXPcgRPIAem1GvrGppYVjC8ZaUit607/BKks9zmMrinm%2BYFzgheKkX47qlgFBD/ZcSjlrf3lynev6lWf2G0aNYmqaZsoHnFqNyOWvKyRNjJHaLZUxDkLGkCwIg/XNlyx9LZtoC80zC/z2ipABmtcTRBSM4SQQA%3D%3D)).

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug; is now fixed. No idea which version this fix will make it into.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96363